# Shiny App e Licença

Tags: r

Bom dia pessoal

Estou com uma duvida em relacao a producao de apps em shiny.

Se eu quiser criar um dashboard e cobrar uma assinatura paga para terem acesso ao meu dashboard eu preciso adquirir alguma licença, para poder vender esse dashboard?

Eu sou professora e quero usar o dasboard como uma ferramenta para o curso. A cobrança para utilizar meu dashboard seria algo irrisorio tipo R$5,00. Apenas para cobrir custos.

Obrigada!

Comment: Não tem advogado ou algum amigo que o seja? Há cursos pagos de produtos (exemplo: R) sob licenças abertas tais como GPL >= 2. Mas não podemos dar qualquer conselho sobre isso. Contacte alguém que saiba de leis de direitos de autor e o [Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/).